# How to restrict file access in Mac os X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want my file to be accessed by only that applications which I permit. For others I want it blocked.
Can I give file read permission to a certain application. 
Or if not Can I interrupt the requests made by another applications which had permission to read the file.

The temp file is generated in my application , and then I pass it to other application.
What I want is that no other application should be able to read that file.

Is there a windows- Exclusive file lock equivalent in mac os.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131109/block-an-applications-read-write-access-to-a-specific-file-in-os-x | http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-the-terminal/

Comment: Unless you encrypt the file in question, it will be readable by some means.

Comment: the irony here is the temp file is the decrypted file!

Comment: Using sandbox rules would be the easiest way of attempting to achieve this; but bear in mind that everything you do will be subject to the limitation that as long as the file is accessible by even one program running as a user; it is, effectively accessible by any program that is running as that user.